# C++ POST request to nodejs server fail(based on socket)

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets, http, post

I have a nodejs server which receive POST request by module 'express',and I need use C++ to send POST request,my client **connect()** and **send()** functions return a number>0,but my server didn't receive anything,and there is no errors.
This is my server code and my C++ code,please help me ,thanks everyone!(My server runs good because when I use js to send request,it can receive the request well.)

The server code:

```
  app.post('/fps', function(req, res){
   var fpsFilename = "./native/Data/FpsFile.txt";
   console.log('execute the imagequality program');

   var exec = require('child_process').exec;
   console.log('in fps post');
   exec('./native/fps ' + fpsFilename, function(err, data, stderr) {
    if(data.length > 1) {
      res.json({fps : data});
    } else {
      console.log('fps file trans error');
    }
    if(err) {
      console.info('stderr from fps:'+stderr);
    }
  });
});
```

my C++ code:

```
#define IPSTR "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 4001
#define BUFSIZE 4096
int MyBasicServerConnector::TestConnect()
{
      int sockfd,ret,i ,h;
      struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
      char str1[4096], str2[2048], buf[BUFSIZE], *str;
      socklen_t len;
      fd_set t_set1;
      struct timeval tv;
      int isConneted = 0;

       if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
          {

                  printf("---------------------socket error!\n");
                   exit(0);
          }

        bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

        if (inet_pton(AF_INET, IPSTR, &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0 )
          {

              printf("---------------------inet_pton error!\n");
              exit(0);

          }

          if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0){     
                    printf("---------------------connect error!\n");
                    exit(0);
          }
          else
          {
            isConneted = 1;
            std::cout <<"---------------------connect success"<<endl;
          }




              memset(str2, 0, 2048);
              //strcat(str2, "name = x\n");
              //strcat(str2, "code = x");
              //str=(char *)malloc(128);
              len = strlen(str2);
              //sprintf(str, "%d", len);

              memset(str1, 0, 4096);
              strcat(str1, "POST /fps HTTP/1.1 \r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Host: 127.0.0.1:4001\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Content-Length: 7\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Accept: */*\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Origin: http://127.0.0.1:4001\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Referer: http://127.0.0.1:4001/\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n");
              strcat(str1, "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n");


        if (isConneted > 0)
        {
            if(send(sockfd,str1 ,strlen(str1),MSG_NOSIGNAL)>0)  
            {  
                cout<<"ok\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"xx\n";
            }
        }
        close (sockfd);
        return 0;
      }
```

Comment: can anyone help me on this ..?this is very urgent,thanks very much!

Comment: Did to compare what C++ send and what JS send using wireshark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you actually study how HTTP work by reading the [standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). There are several errors in your post. The most obvious are:

- There should be no space after `HTTP/1.1` in the first line of the request
- You declare a content-length of 7 but don't send any body data
- There is no end of header delimiter (empty line `\r\n`)